# JavaFX input field doesn't accept tabulators

Tags: java, javafx

So I have probably an easy question, but I couldn't find anyone asking this question on Google, so now I'm here.

The problem is simple - I must copy a line of text that has white spaces and tabulators in it, but once I copy it inside my text (input) field, it removes all the tabulators for some reason, so it leave the text all in one big mess that I cannot filter anything out of it.

Any ideas what could be done so those input fields would allow tabulators?

P.S. By pressing tab while I'm inside the input field, it moves between the buttons, instead of inputting a tabulator.

Comment: [mcve] please..

Answer (score 0):

The content of a `TextField` is represented by a private static class `TextFieldContent`.  `TextFieldContent` implements `insert(int index, String text, boolean notifyListeners)` method to filter the input text. The method uses a static method from `TextInputControl` class to remove "illegal" characters, here is the implementation:

```java
@Override 
public void insert(int index, String text, boolean notifyListeners) {
    text = TextInputControl.filterInput(text, true, true);
    if (!text.isEmpty()) {
        characters.insert(index, text);
        if (notifyListeners) {
            ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(helper);
        }
    }
}
```

The last parameter in `TextInputControl.filterInput(text, true, true)` defines whether tab characters are *"illegal"* or not. It's set to `true` and as I mentioned before, that class is a private static final class and **you can't extend it and override `insert` method**.

The solution is to extend `TextInputControl` and create a custom `Content` class that doesn't remove tab characters.

As an alternative, you can use `TextArea`, text areas accept tab characters.

Comment: Ah, so it is limited internally. I'm relatively new to programming, I know some things, but I haven't used class extensions and interfaces yet - is it hard to extend and create the custom class, so my text fields accept tabulators? I have no idea how to go about this, should I create a new class that extends TextInputControl and then somehow create a Content class?

Comment: @Eddie that's the way to do it, but if you're a beginner, that would be harder. Try to use a `TextArea` instead.